# A question about conditional expectation $E[X_1 | X_1 + X_2]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two iid random variables. I'm trying to find a formula for $E[X_1|X_1+ X_2]$.  I was trying to show this
$$E[X_1| X_1 + X_2 ]= \frac{E[X_1(X_1 + X_2)]}{E[X_1+ X_2]}$$
but I don't think it's true. Could you give me a tip  to finda a counterexample of this?

Comment: Any non-constant $X_1$ is a counterexample to your claim.  Pick your favorite.

Comment: Hint: $\mathbf{E}(X_1 + X_2 | X_1 + X_2) = X_1 + X_2$ and $\mathbf{E}(X_1| X_1 + X_2) = \mathbf{E}(X_2| X_1 + X_2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true.

$\qquad\mathsf E(X_1\mid X_1+X_2)$ is a random variable (a function of $X_1+X_2$), whereas the quotient is a constant.

For a quick example:

Let $X_1, X_2$ be Bernoulli($1/2$) random variables, so that:

$\qquad\mathsf P(X_1+X_2=z)~=~\begin{cases}1/4 &:&  z=0\\1/2 &:& z=1\\1/4&:& z=2\\ 0&:& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Then $\mathsf E(X_1\mid X_1+X_2)=\dfrac {(X_1+X_2)}{2}$ while $\dfrac{\mathsf E\big(X_1(X_1+X_2)\big)}{\mathsf E(X_1+X_2)}=\dfrac{3}{4}$ .

But any independent random variables will suffice.

Comment: Yes it is true. I had forgotten that $E[X_1| X_1 + X_2]$ is a function of $X_1+X_2$. So I don't think there is any formula for this. I tried $E[X_1 | X_1 + X_2]= E[ E[X_1 | X_1 + X_2] | X_1,X_2 ]$ or $E[X_1 | X_1 + X_2]= E[ E[X_1 | X_1,X_2 ] | X_1 + X_2 ]$, but nothing more. That's it, right?